# WPF datagrid start editing new item

Tags: wpf, datagrid, command, new-operator

I have a datagrid with editable items in it and I have a button to create a new instance of such an item. The datagrid is updated with the new item but I can't select the recently added item and start editing on it.

Below is my code:

```
  private void btnNewKenmerk_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
  {
   Kenmerk newKenmerk = new Kenmerk(); // the item to add

   Kenmerken.Add( newKenmerk ); // this is an observablecollection. the datagrid (dgKenmerken) has this as itemssource

   // deselect all other items except our new kenmerk
   for( int i = 0; i < dgKenmerken.Items.Count; i++ )
   {
    Kenmerk kenmerk = ( Kenmerk )dgKenmerken.Items[ i ];
    DataGridRow dgRow = ( DataGridRow )dgKenmerken.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex( i );

    if( dgRow != null )
    {
     dgRow.IsSelected = ( kenmerk == newKenmerk );
    }
   }

   dgKenmerken.SelectedItem = newKenmerk;

   // start editing
   if( DataGrid.BeginEditCommand.CanExecute( newKenmerk, dgKenmerken ) )
   {
    DataGrid.BeginEditCommand.Execute( newKenmerk, dgKenmerken );
   }
  }
```

The item is added and the background of the row is changed, but the BeginEditCommand starts editing on my previous selected item, not the added item. Anyone has any clue how to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps check your SelectedIndex? I've occasionally had that different then my SelectedItem and perhaps the edit command uses SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem. `dgKenmerken.SelectedIndex = dgKenmerken.Items.Count-1`

Comment: Rachel, using SelectedIndex did not work. I used this code:

 dgKenmerken.SelectedIndex = dgKenmerken.Items.IndexOf(newKenmerk);|

and that changed the SelectedIndex and SelectedItem to the new item but still didn't initiate an edit on that item

Answer (score 1):

It is because the datagrid does not "see" changes immediately. Postpone using your newly added data -- please try splitting your method into two -- one adding, the second using. Call the second from the first one, not directly, but via dispatcher.